# How I can made an Upload using Angular2x and Strapi.JS?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, strapi

I have the APIs made with Strapi.js and I want to upload photos and documents with the Angular 2x.

I saw the path to file. But I can´t get the name of the file. And if sending an image with the same name? The documentation of Strapi.js is weak.

How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a FormData.
Bellow the jQuery code. You just have to adapte it for any front-end framework you want

```
  <form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var data = new FormData();

      $.each($('#files')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('files', file);
      });

      $.ajax({
        url: '/upload',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST'
      });
    });
  </script>
```